# I can not access service from wildfly server deployed war file 405 methode not allowed

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

I installed wildfly server on mac, after that I deployed one maven project war file on that server, but I can't access my services.

It was giving errors like

**405 Methode not Allowed** in postman.

```html
<html>
<head>
     <title>Error</title>
</head>
    <body>405 - Method Not Allowed</body>
</html>
```

I already installed plugin in that file also like:

```xml
<groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.1.0.Alpha11</version>
<configuration>
<hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>
<port>9990</port>
<username>admin</username>
<password>admin</password>
<name>spring4ajax.war</name>
</configuration>
```

**.War file completely running on tomcat server**

How can I solve this?

Comment: You need to show the code, where you implemented the service, seems the server isn't expecting a GET request in that url..

Comment: @tiagocvboas thankyou so much.but i changed my whole code